# Looping through a list is throwing an Out of boundaries exception C#

Tags: c#, list, loops

Would anybody help me to understand what is wrong with this for loop why am I getting out of boundaries exception please?

**Capacity of this particular list is set to 8.**

```
public static List<Beds> BedsList = new List<Beds>(8); 

private int GetFirstAvailableBed()
    {
        var result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Beds.BedsList.Capacity; i++)
        {
            if (Beds.BedsList[i] == null) // Here is trhowing the exception
            {
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Is the BedList.Capacity *really* it's capacity?

Comment: @Idos Yes on debug is showing 8

Comment: Can you show the initialization of your variables?

Comment: What's `BedsList`? What type is it?

Comment: @Idos The question is edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [**`List#Count`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Beds.BedsList.Count; i++)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `List.Count` instead of `List.Capacity`.

The [`Capacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) property

> Gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure can hold without resizing.

It's not the number of items in the list.